# why refresh html page is slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason the method display is being processed before location.reload(). Here is my syntax:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#refresh").click(function() {
    alert("before refresh")
    location.reload();
    display()
  })
})

function display() {
  alert("hello world")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="refresh">
  refersh and continue
</button>
```

My goal here is to refresh the page when the button is clicked then call display method. 
The problem is that display method is being called before the page is refreshed.
First of all, is what I am trying to achieve achievable. If not, what other ways can go take in order to solve the problem?

Comment: You need to put the refresh method inside the document ready and inside a condition that should be set to whatever when click on `#refresh` element. Maybe you can use `localStorage()` for this

Comment: `First of all, is what I am trying to achieve achievable` Yes - but not in the manner you're attempting. You need to show the `alert()` in the load of the page. You cannot do anything in a page after an unload event has been called (as it would be when you call `reload()`) as the page no longer exists.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That seems right, but it actually IS calling the `display()` function, even though it's after `location.reload()`. Why is that?

Comment: Is `location.reload()` asynchronous, so it continues executing the current script first?

Comment: @Barmar you're right - that is a little odd. I would agree that it does seem async. Perhaps there is a slight delay in killing the JS in the current page thread before loading the next which allows some following logic to still be executed.

Comment: @Barmar and Rory the problem I am facing is a bit more complicated that shown above. The project I am working seems to release unnecessary(interrupting) data only when the page is reloaded so that it thinks that it is the first visit to the page.

Comment: that is why I came up with idea of adding a refresh button to the page so that I can get rid of the unnecessary data

Comment: if you know any alternative method to location.reload(), you are more than welcome to let me know

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
display();
  $("#refresh").click(function(){
    alert("before refresh")
    //location.reload();
  display();
  });
})

function display(){
    alert("hello world")
}

    </script>
<button id="refresh">
refersh and continue
</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Try this, call the display method on loading the document and remove the reload(), if needed add display() in refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You could try assigning your `display` method to the `document.onload` event. Try changing your click handler to:

```
alert('before refresh');
$(document).on('load', display);
location.reload;
```